# Doctrine 2: Entity has no field or association named when trying to leftJoin()

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

Trying to build a query with doctrine, getting error:

`Entity has no field or association named some_id`

code (t is test table, it has some_id and i join it with Example ON example.id = test.some_id):

`->from('AppBundle:Test', 't')
->leftJoin('AppBundle:Example', 'e', 'WITH', 'e.id = t.some_id')`

Test Entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="some_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $someId;
```

Column some_id exists in my database, and a simple SQL query works fine, im just getting this error when trying to build it with query manager. Im guessing im missing something in my entity, but not sure what exactly.

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer..

it has to be:

`->leftJoin('AppBundle:Example', 'e', 'WITH', 'e.id = t.someId')`

`someId` instead of `some_id`